# Using "both" for the subject definition in a negation

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, negation

As advised by @TRomano in my previous question concerning the use of [Either in a negative sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117321/either-in-a-negative-sentence) I ask about the word `both` in the same role. Here are the examples:

> 1. Both this and that fruit are not tasty.
> 2. Both cars are not for sale.
> 3. Both students will not be restricted.
> 4. Both of the lakes are not polluted.
> 5. Both paths have not been taken.

Do those sentences sound unnatural? May be even ungrammatical? Or maybe just slightly off?

As I mentioned in my other question, I do not need any help rephrasing those statements using `neither`. That's an obvious way and a good one too.

My particular concern here is the word `both` being used for subject in a negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those statements do not sound good.
*Or, more normally*, None of those statements sound good.

Generally, a phrase or sentence has a particular [polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_and_negative): either positive or negative.   In English, there are only a few [negative-polarity markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item): *not, no, never, nowhere, nothing, nobody.*  When you use one of these markers in a phrase, you "gain license" to use certain words, and "lose license" for others.  (I keep being tempted to call these "negative-concord" words, but that is a different (though related) concept.)
In particular, in a negative context, *both* becomes *neither* (which also changes plurality: "both are for sale" -> "Neither is for sale").  See the "determination of licensing contexts" section of the wikipedia article on [Polarity Items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) for more details.

Thus, *both* is not allowed in any of your sentences; *Neither* is the correct word in all of them.

Comment: I agree. Does it change if we say **Both of these cars are not for sale**?

Comment: @Tromano, I took a more emphatic position and added some references and details.  To answer your question, no; you still can't use *both* there, because *both* is only licensed in a positive statement, and the presence of *not* makes your statement negative.

Comment: @Hellion Nevertheless, composition "both are not" is definitely above zero on ngram: https://goo.gl/yb2fK8

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are not to my taste. Both doesn't work well here.

Both is not used in any of these examples. Both could be used like this:

Both cars are mine.

Both of my children go to school here.

I like both of them.

Both lakes are clean and unpolluted.

**Both** is usually used in a positive way.